# Semicolon splits fields when export as a CSV file?

Tags: php, csv, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I exported the reviews from my magento website in csv format. Reviews contains `:,;,?,!` etc. Normally reviews are well in  fields. When the review contain `;` ,it's get splitted to next field. (I opened the csv file using OpenOffice spreadsheet)

For Example:

```
Review -> It's nice to use; looks good.
```

Now output ->

```
Field A-> It's nice to use
Field B->  looks good
```

Expected Output

```
Field A ->It's nice to use; looks good
```

I used the following header to export as acsv file in php

```
header('Content-type: application/utf-8');  
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');
```

How can I get my expected output?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, and everything with how you get Openoffice to import that file. If OO is treating the `;` as a separator, then that's not PHP's fault. YOU told PHP to use `;`. And if the `;` is naturally inside your text, and you're using it as a the CSV separator, then again that's your fault. CSV is a last-resort export format, because there is NO universal standard for encapsulating/escaping text in a CSV. Some engines might like `\;`, some engines might want `;;` instead.

Comment: iirc there is some way to escape the semicolon / any delimiter, but really, just use something other for delimiter. \t perhaps.

Comment: also, if you put your string in "quotes", doesn't it help?

Comment: @MightyPork Yes I have used quotes, even after I'm facing this issue!

Comment: It all depends on what you select in the CSV import dialog. It's really an ugly format, I've had issues w/ it as well when I used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise tackling the problem from the other side - I believe this is a bone of contention for Magento as some users want the semi-colon.

I would suggest looking at the way you use openoffice - It has been a while but I believe there is an option during the load of the csv called "Separator options" - Change these and all should work well.

The sad thing is if this is the correct answer it is off topic :-( but I hope this helps you achieve your goal!

Thanks,
//P

Comment: Yes! You are right. I could see the separator options.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this class I've made for exporting data as a CSV spreadsheet. The trick is `fputcsv()` which should do the formatting right. Then, of course, you must properly import it to OpenOffice (or LibreOffice now), but that's different story.

Maybe it'll help you out.

```
<?php

class Spreadsheet {

    private $grid = array();

    /**
     * Set cell value at position X, Y
     */
    public function setCell($x, $y, $value) {
        for($yy=0; $yy<=$y; $yy++) {
            if(!isset($this->grid[$yy])) {
                $this->grid[$yy] = array();
            }
        }

        for($xx=0; $xx<=$x; $xx++) {
            if(!isset($this->grid[$y][$xx])) {
                $this->grid[$y][$xx] = null;
            }
        }

        $this->grid[$y][$x] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * final command executed, including "exit".
     * Sends CSV to browser.
     */
    public function sendAsCsv(/*string*/ $filename) {
        header('Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Language: cs');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");

        ob_end_clean();

        $outputBuffer = fopen("php://output", 'w');

        $this->appendToFile($outputBuffer);

        fclose($outputBuffer);
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * Appends content to a file (rarely used outside this class)
     */
    public function appendToFile(/*resource*/ $fileHandle) {
        foreach($this->grid as $val) {
            fputcsv($fileHandle, $val);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course I don't know what Magento is, but I believe you can make it work with this class. Just fill in the cells, and export.